# Doxygen's call graph for C++ unable to figure out invocations from double pointer

Tags: c++, doxygen, call-graph

I have code of the type

```
void Foo::someMethod(std::vector<Bar*>& vector) {
  for (std::vector<Bar*>::const_iterator cit = vector.cbegin(); cit != vector.cend(); ++cit) {
    (*cit)->invoke();
  }
}
```

The issue is that I do not see in the call graph `Foo::someMethod` -> `Bar::invoke`. I do see the invocations when I iterate over a `std::vector<Bar>` using an iterator as well. Any thoughts what parameters I need to tweak in the Doxygen config to make it work?  I'm using `Doxygen 1.8.15`

I have an identical issue of the missing call graph with code of type `getBar().invoke()` but I'd imagine this is too much to ask from `Doxygen`.

Comment: Please also show the code for the working version.

Comment: Even better would be a small project that can be ran directly.